# Cascading dropdown lists with minimum js code usage for multiple purpose window (update and create)

Tags: razor

Here is my cshtml code for cascading dropdownlist. Is there a way that i can make these cascading dropdowns with just razor with minimum js code usage if it is possible. I am living trouble with js. This page is using for both create and update so i need cascading values from dropdowns if i am creating something new also when i need update i must get current values of them.

```
@{
    var dataSource = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
    var LstPlant = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.LstPlant);
    var LstArea = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.LstArea);
    var LstAreaLine = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.LstAreaLine);
    var LstPartList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.LstPartList);
    var JoinedResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.JoinedResult);
}
```

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="fo-select-outline">
                <select id="idPlant" name="PlantId" class="select-text" required>
                    <!option disabled selected>@localize.GetString("Choose")</!option>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LstPlant)
                    {
                        <!option @(Model.PlantId == @item.Id ? "selected" : null) value="@item.Id" data-username="@item.CdPlant">@item.CdPlant</!option>
                    }
                </select>
                <label class="select-label">@localize.GetString("Plant")</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="fo-select-outline">
                <select id="idArea" name="AreaId" class="select-text" required>
                    <!option disabled selected>@localize.GetString("Choose")</!option>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LstArea)
                    {
                        <!option @(Model.AreaId == @item.Id ? "selected" : null) value="@item.Id" data-username="@item.ChArea">@item.ChArea</!option>
                    }
                </select>
                <label class="select-label">@localize.GetString("ProductionArea")</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="fo-select-outline">
                <select id="idAreaLine" name="AreaLineId" class="select-text" required>
                    <!option disabled selected>@localize.GetString("Choose")</!option>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LstAreaLine)
                    {
                        <!option @(Model.AreaLineId == @item.Id ? "selected" : null) value="@item.Id" data-username="@item.ChProdLine">@item.ChProdLine</!option>
                    }
                </select>
                <label class="select-label">@localize.GetString("ProductionLine")</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```